# Using PowerShell to Run a Script that installs some files from a mapped drive

Tags: windows, powershell, network-drive

I have a folder that has some install files for new user computers and  need to create a script that runs the install files from a folder that is located on a network drive that's mapped to my computer.

I'm running the below script from PowerShell but I'm getting an error

> Join-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'Z' does not
> exist

I'm running as admin and I've set the execution policy to remote signed so it allows me to run the script.

Below is the start of the script. Im testing one exe. file and will add more once I actually get this to run and perform a successful install.

```
$folderPath ="Z:\HD\NEW PC SET UP\chrome"

$exeFileName = "ChromeSetup.exe"

$exePath = Join-Path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $exeFileName

if(Test-Path $exePath -PathType Leaf){
    Start-Process -FilePath $exePath
} else {
    Write-Host "Executable not found: $exePath"

}
```

From what I gathered so far it seems I need to remap the network drive to an unused letter and then access it as a normal drive ? Not sure if I'm going down the right path on this.

nothing yet as im not sure if remapping the drive in the script is the proper way to do this

Comment: Is there a reason you need to map the network share? Powershell is perfectly capable of using network shares.  Find out what the network path is of "Z:". You can use "net use" on a system that has it mapped.  Then just use the full share name instead of the drive letter.  for example you can do something like this: $exePath = Join-Path \\acmecorp\shared $exeFileName

Comment: It's quite normal in an elevated prompt (both PS and cmd) to not have the drive mappings available, since you're running in a different user context. If you did add the mapping there's nothing stopping you mapping it to the same letter, eg `net use Z: \\server\sharename` but as @Tolga has said you could just as easily reference the UNC path directly.

Answer (score 0):

Drive mappings are per user and running as an admin counts as being a different user.

Open a powershell prompt as your account (not elevated) and run the following command and you should see your Z: drive:

```
get-psdrive -PSProvider Filesystem
```

if you then run the same command in your elevated command prompt, you will not see any shares

to fix this, you need to add the share using `New-PsDrive` (after checking it doesn't already exist)

Alternatively, Powershell supports UNC paths so you could do away with the drive mapping altogether